# What is the name of this spider and is it poisonous?

Tags: species, poison

[image]
We found it between Palm trees in the backyard of a home in West Palm Beach Florida.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, that would be the spiny orb weaver. You can see an almost exact [same picture here](https://bugguide.net/node/view/721344/bgimage). To make a guess on the species, its maybe *Gasteracantha cancriformis* as its said in that webpage I have tagged. They are generally harmless. Here's the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiny_orb-weaver).